# Redactor II image resizing?

Tags: redactor, wysiwyg

What is the preferred image handling method when using the WYSIWYG editor? Are inline transforms the only way to prevent large images, or are there any other solutions?

Although I am aware of offering more control by "bodybuilding" the front end, this question is specifically related to the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting Brad Bell in a recent [thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17927/how-to-add-redactor-image-resizing-and-positioning-to-the-rich-text-field-in-cra):

> If you're on Craft 2.6.2950 or greater, it includes Redactor II 1.3.1,
>   where they re-introduced image resizing and positioning support.
>
> You'll just need to add:
>
> imageResizable: true, imagePosition: true to whatever
>   craft/config/redactor config file your Rich Text field is set to use
>   under its settings.

This combined with the mentioned 3rd party plugins creates a bullet proof and front-end friendly setup.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this superb plugin:

**[RetconHTML](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft)**

> Ever have a client put 4 MB PNG files in their Redactor fields, failing to apply any of your meticulously crafted image transforms? Writers consistently using the  tag for headers? Have you ever needed to implement lazy loading of images embedded in WYSIWYG content, responsive images or wanted to remove pesky inline styles without breaking a sweat? This is for you.

It is super easy. Just add this filter to your WYSIWYG template.

`{{ entry.wysiwyg | retcon('transform', 'yourImageTransform') }}`

As an option you can install [Imager](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft).
If installed, Retcon uses Imager to apply the transform. Imager is faster and more flexibel than the standard image transforms in Craft.

Comment: Thanks Johan, I did explore both plugins, but this is my first site and next to P&T's commerce plugin I already racked up 9 other 3rd party plugins, despite my best intentions to build this "pure". I had bigger expectations to do something rudimentary as I propose here out-of-the-box.