# How to add Redactor Image resizing and positioning to the Rich Text field in Craft?

Tags: redactor

Can anyone provide details on how to add Redactor (II) Image resizing and positioning to the Rich Text field in Craft?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on [Craft 2.6.2950](https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-6-2950) or greater, it includes Redactor II 1.3.1, where they re-introduced image [resizing and positioning](https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/image-resize/) support.

You'll just need to add:

```
imageResizable: true,
imagePosition: true
```

to whatever `craft/config/redactor` config file your Rich Text field is set to use under its settings.

Answer (score 1):

Similar [Q&A](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17607/redactor-ii-image-resizing/17933#17933) with additional bulletproofing techniques using 3rd party plugins.

Example for Standard.json:

```
{
    "buttons": ["format","bold","italic","lists","link","file","horizontalrule"],
    "plugins": ["source","fullscreen"],
    imageResizable: true,
    imagePosition: true

}
```